# Working with objects in socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, redis, socket.io

Here is my app.js

```
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {

    //console.log('Redis: Message on ' + channel + ' received!');
    //
    //message1 = JSON.parse(message).object;
    //console.log(message1);
    //console.log(message1.question_model_user_id);

    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit('new', message);

});

console.log('user connected');

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
});
```

now my client script

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('new',function(data){
    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        console.log(value);
      //$.each( value, function( key, value1 ) {
      //    $.each( value1, function( key, value3 ) {
      //        console.log(key);
      //    });
      //});
    });
```

Now user A have one object and user B has 0 object. Whenever A refreshes the page B should get one object but i am getting many objects as the same objects increases like +1  if user A refreshes the page only once.

Comment: A question would be welcome. What is `redit` on your server code ? We need context to understand what you mean.

Comment: Oh i am sending the object on the test-channel via redis subscribe so if the subscribe is made redis.on message would run user a has one object which has 8 array and b got 0 object now whenever a refresh b would get one object now next time if b refresh a gets empty object now if a refresh b get 2 objects?

Comment: issue has been resolved some one told me to io.emit to send objects to all the connected client and i used socket.emit now the objects are not getting +1 every time page is being refresh thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use io.socket instead of io.emit to emit the object oncee